# Fixed header and footer issue on blackberry Application using phonegap?

Tags: javascript, cordova, blackberry, phonegap-plugins

I am writing Blackberry apps using the Phonegap framework.

I have an issue with headers and footers.

I can't seem to set a fixed position to headers and footers. I have tried iScroll, but it doesn't work on Blackberry devices.

Comment: Which version of Phonegap are you using? What other libraries are you using (jqtouch, jquerymobile, sencha etc) - can you provide some example code or a jsfiddle so we have something to work with?

Answer (score 0):

On a non-touch screen blackberry: use "position: absolute" for your header and footer with "position: static" for your content. Have a method that refreshes and positions your elements on the page on the window resize event and whenever you need to update the page because the content changes. Use "padding-top: " and "padding-bottom: " on your content element to make room for the header and footer when scrolled all the way to the top or all the way to the bottom. Good luck!